# Using Mobile Accelerometer to trigger an action in my game unity

Tags: unity, mobile

Hi I have this project I'm working on which is a bowling game controlled by mobile acceleration. I want the following:

when the player holds the phone up facing him for 2 seconds to enter strike state.
then he should rotate the phone all the way down and facing the other side then lift it halfway to call the action.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I got to a partial solution where I use 3 booleans one for when the phone is up the second is when the phone is down and the third is when the phone is in the middle. Then in the update, I check certain condition to get the movement I want from the player before I call the action...

Comment: Okay, so what is the issue you're facing?